# innerHtml with domSanitizer not accept attributes natives of angular

Tags: angular

I'm creating dynamic html with angular, and I can not make it correctly take the native attributes of angular.
this is working correctly in @Component template, but this dose not work within any variable.

...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-canvas-render',
  template: `<div [innerHtml]="this.objHtmlElement | domSanitizer: 'safeHtml'"></div>`,
})
export class CanvasRenderComponent implements OnInit {

  objHtmlElement = `<div div *ngFor="let element1 of objSchemaElement"
         [id]="element1.id" [index]="element1.index" class="edited"
         [ngStyle]="this.objElements[element1.index].styles | convertToStyle"
         [appStyleEditCanvas]="this.objStylesLogs.slice(-1)[0]">
      {{element1.id}} - {{element1.index}} - {{element1.type}}
    </div>`;
```

...

the actual output is:

```
{{element1.id}} - {{element1.index}} - {{element1.type}}
```

and the output html code is:

```
<div div *ngfor="let element1 of objSchemaElement"
         [id]="element1.id" [index]="element1.index" class="edited"
         [ngstyle]="this.objElements[element1.index].styles | convertToStyle"
         [appstyleeditcanvas]="this.objStylesLogs.slice(-1)[0]">
     {{element1.id}} - {{element1.index}} - {{element1.type}}
</div>
```

Comment: The innerHTML is passed as HTML, not as a template. If you want different templates depending on the object type, you can define `<ng-template>`s in your component's template and use them.

Answer (score 0):

Using innerHTML will not work for HTML that contains Angular directives like that. You will need to use dynamic components to accomplish that. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753464/how-to-use-reactive-forms-in-a-dynamic-component) and the subsequent answer. That should get you started in the right direction.

Here is cleaned up and simplified version of a dynamic component working in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mlc-app-init-ekvhth). Hope that helps :)