# Way to inject angular FormBuilder service to dynamic component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-reactive-forms, angular-services, angular-dynamic-components

I'm trying to inject the FormBuilder service to a dynamic component this way:

**Template:**

```html
...
<div #vc></div>
...
```

**Component:**

```js
@ViewChild('vc', { read: ViewContainerRef }) _container: ViewContainerRef;

...

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private _compiler: Compiler, private _injector: Injector,
    private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) {
  }

...

ngAfterViewInit() {
    let  allPms: any[] = null;
    let template = '';

    // construct template on the fly

    const wTypes = this._f.w_type;

    for (const plug of this._plugs) {
      if (plug.name === wTypes) {
        allPms = plug.params;
      }
    }

    for (const pm of allPms) {
      if (pm.type === 'str') {
        template = template + `
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label"><strong>` + pm.name + `</strong></label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input class="form-control" name="` + pm.name + `" type="text"
              formControlName="` + pm.name + `">
          </div>
        </div>
        `;
      }
    }

    // add field for each pm

    let injector1 = Injector.create([
      {
        provide: 'FormBuilder',
        useValue: FormBuilder
      }
    ]);

    const tmpCmp = Component({ template: template, styles: [`label {
      width: 128px;
      margin: 0px 8px;
    }`] })(class {
      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
      }
    });
    const tmpModule = NgModule({ declarations: [tmpCmp] })(class {
    });

    this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
      .then((factories) => {
        const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
        this.cmpRef = f.create(injector1, [], null, this._m);
        this.cmpRef.instance.name = 'B component';
        this._container.insert(this.cmpRef.hostView);
      })
  }
```

Doing so, I got this error:

```
  ERROR Error: Can't resolve all parameters for class_1: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:1021)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:10922)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:10815)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:10434)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:10296)
    at compiler.js:23883
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at compiler.js:23882
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:23879)
View_testComponent_17 @ testComponent.html:72
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError @ core.js:11306
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1719
(anonymous) @ core.js:4578
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:3779
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:4578
(anonymous) @ core.js:4462
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
onInvoke @ core.js:3820
```

Trying to add a custom injector did not help:

```
 let injector1 = Injector.create([
  {
    provide: 'FormBuilder',
    useValue: FormBuilder
  }
]);
```

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-components-example-2mjjrc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) that reproduces the issue:

[angular-dynamic-components-example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-components-example-2mjjrc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[image]

Is there any way to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Can you please reproduce this issue in stackblitz?

Comment: I think that the error is because you has forgot import `ReactiveFormsModule` in the app.module.ts -well in the module where you has your component-. But you **can not** "inject" in a `[innerHTML]` a html string like you want it. Angular don't "compile at runtime" the .html in a div.

Comment: @yurzui: OK will check if I can create the Stackblitz.

Comment: is there any way to use dynamic `import()` and async/await to resolve the missing parameters ? [angular-dynamic-importing-large-libraries](https://medium.com/lacolaco-blog/angular-dynamic-importing-large-libraries-8ec079603d0)

Comment: I'm using this documentation to try to create dynamic component for simple forms, that do not change a lot, the fields to add to the template depend of the JSON object received from back end: [Creating components on the fly](https://indepth.dev/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular/)

Comment: Are you completely tied to building the dynamic component in that exact way you're doing it now? If not, you could adjust your code like I did in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mlc-app-init-ofjruo?file=app/app.component.ts) which shows an alternative approach that works well.

Comment: @Narm: not sure if it's a best practice for performance and design to inject an entire component with some unrelated business logic to the dynamic component just to satisfy some dependency injection or library dependencies ...

Comment: I believe your code will work if you disable the minification for your Angular application. Could you please check that?

Comment: @yurzui: StackBlitz is added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` sign in errors like `Can't resolve all parameters for class_1: (?)` means that Angular can't resolve type of parameter passed to constructor. In other words, reflector can't recognize that `private fb: FormBuilder` parameter has `FormBuilder` type because type dissappers after TypeScript compilation.

In order to tell TS compiler that it should keep this type you need to rewrite this class definition to version with decorator like:

```
@Component({
  template: template,
  styles: [
    `
      label {
        width: 128px;
        margin: 0px 8px;
      }
    `
  ]
})
class tmpCmp {
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-components-example-epimjt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

This will be compiled to:

```
tmpCmp = __decorate([
    core_1.Component({
        template: template,
        styles: [
            `
label {
width: 128px;
margin: 0px 8px;
}
`
        ]
    }),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [typeof (_a = typeof forms_1.FormBuilder !== "undefined" && forms_1.FormBuilder) === "function" ? _a : Object])
], tmpCmp);
```

where you can notice `__metadata("design:paramtypes"` part which is responsible for providing information to Angular reflector.

There are other ways of solving it.

### Static parameters

```
const tmpCmp = Component({
  ...
})(
  class {
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

    static parameters = [ FormBuilder ]
  }
);
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-components-example-yffxpn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

### Static ctorParameters method

```
const tmpCmp = Component({
 ...
})(
  class {
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

    static ctorParameters = () => [{ type: FormBuilder} ]
  }
);
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-components-example-anq8vs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**